# How to only allow POST Requests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I prevent users from calling a method "doAction" in my controller using GET requests? I only want it to be called using POST requests?

I heard I need to use "verify" but I'm unsure where to put that code, or how I need to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify which methods are allowed for any action in your `routes.rb`.

Rails 2:

```
map.connect '/posts/doAction', :controller => 'posts,
                               :action     => 'doAction',
                               :conditions => { :method => :post }
```

Rails 3:

```
match 'posts/doAction' => "posts#doAction', :via => :post

post 'posts/doAction', :to => "posts#doAction'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a constraint to the route in `routes.rb`.

```
match "/doAction" => "controller#doAction", :via => :post
```

Refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more.